# Is Payment Required for GoDaddy OTE (Test) Environment?

Tags: godaddy-api

I'm trying to use the [GoDaddy Purchase Domain API](https://developer.godaddy.com/doc/endpoint/domains#/v1/purchase) on their OTE environment, but I keep getting the error below, which suggests that some payment is required:

```json
{
  "code": "INVALID_PAYMENT_INFO",
  "message": "Unable to authorize credit based on specified payment information"
}
```

How can I go around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reaching out to their customer support, and they made some changes on their end that allowed me to proceed.